# How to do a database insert with SQFlite in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

How do you insert data into a database in Flutter using the SQFlite plugin?

There are a number of problem solving questions out there but none that I could find to add a canonical answer to. My answer is below.

Comment: There is also a recipe for this here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Add the dependencies

Open `pubspec.yaml` and in the dependency section add the following lines:

```
sqflite: ^1.0.0
path_provider: ^0.4.1
```

The `sqflite` is the [SQFlite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) plugin of course and the `path_provider` will help us get the user directory on Android and iPhone.

## Make a database helper class

I'm keeping a global reference to the database in a singleton class. This will prevent concurrency issues and data leaks (that's what I hear, but tell me if I'm wrong). You can also add helper methods (like insert) in here for accessing the database.

Create a new file called *database_helper.dart* and paste in the following code:

```
import 'dart:io' show Directory;
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' show getApplicationDocumentsDirectory;

class DatabaseHelper {

  static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";
  static final _databaseVersion = 1;

  static final table = 'my_table';

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnName = 'name';
  static final columnAge = 'age';

  // make this a singleton class
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  // only have a single app-wide reference to the database
  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    // lazily instantiate the db the first time it is accessed
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  // this opens the database (and creates it if it doesn't exist)
  _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
    return await openDatabase(path,
        version: _databaseVersion,
        onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  // SQL code to create the database table
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnName TEXT NOT NULL,
            $columnAge INTEGER NOT NULL
          )
          ''');
  }
}
```

## Insert data

We'll use an async method to do our insert:

```
  _insert() async {

    // get a reference to the database
    // because this is an expensive operation we use async and await
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

    // row to insert
    Map<String, dynamic> row = {
      DatabaseHelper.columnName : 'Bob',
      DatabaseHelper.columnAge  : 23
    };

    // do the insert and get the id of the inserted row
    int id = await db.insert(DatabaseHelper.table, row);

    // show the results: print all rows in the db
    print(await db.query(DatabaseHelper.table));
  }
```

Notes

- You will have to import the `DatabaseHelper` class and `sqflite` if you are in another file (like main.dart).
- The SQFlite plugin uses a `Map<String, dynamic>` to map the column names to the data in each row.
- We didn't specify the `id`. SQLite auto increments it for us.

#### Raw insert

SQFlite also supports doing a raw insert. This means that you can use a SQL string. Lets insert the same row again using `rawInsert()`.

```
db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO my_table(name, age) VALUES("Bob", 23)');
```

Of course, we wouldn't want to hard code those values into the SQL string, but we also wouldn't want to use interpelation like this:

```
String name = 'Bob';
int age = 23;
db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO my_table(name, age) VALUES($name, $age)'); // Dangerous!
```

That would open us up to SQL injection attacks. Instead we can use data binding like this:

```
db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO my_table(name, age) VALUES(?, ?)', [name, age]);
```

The `[name, age]` are filled in for the question mark placeholders in `(?, ?)`. The table and column names are safer to use interpelation for, so we could do this finally:

```
String name = 'Bob';
int age = 23;
db.rawInsert(
    'INSERT INTO ${DatabaseHelper.table}'
        '(${DatabaseHelper.columnName}, ${DatabaseHelper.columnAge}) '
        'VALUES(?, ?)', [name, age]);
```

## Supplemental code

[image]

For your copy-and-paste convenience, here is the layout code for `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_db_operations/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SQFlite Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('sqflite'),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('insert', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
        onPressed: () {_insert();},
      ),
    );
  }

  _insert() async {

    // get a reference to the database
    // because this is an expensive operation we use async and await
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

    // row to insert
    Map<String, dynamic> row = {
      DatabaseHelper.columnName : 'Bob',
      DatabaseHelper.columnAge  : 23
    };

    // do the insert and get the id of the inserted row
    int id = await db.insert(DatabaseHelper.table, row);

    // raw insert
    //
    //  String name = 'Bob';
    //  int age = 23;
    //  int id = await db.rawInsert(
    //    'INSERT INTO ${DatabaseHelper.table}'
    //          '(${DatabaseHelper.columnName}, ${DatabaseHelper.columnAge}) '
    //          'VALUES(?, ?)', [name, age]);

    print(await db.query(DatabaseHelper.table));
  }

}
```

## Going on

- This post is a development from my previous post: [Simple SQFlite database example in Flutter](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/simple-sqflite-database-example-in-flutter-e56a5aaa3f91). See that post for other SQL operations and advice.

Comment: I don't find it that useful to have a `helper` class (at least for the use-case here in work), but this is a pattern that might be useful

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, I like the helper class because as a Singleton it guarantees only one open connection to the database. Now I combine this with [services](https://medium.com/flutter-community/creating-services-to-do-the-work-in-your-flutter-app-93d6c4aa7697).

Comment: This is a very informative post, thank you. One question: as DatabaseHelper is a singleton, what's the benefit of making the other member variables static, as shouldn't there only be one instance anyway of this class?

Comment: @Kdon, good question. I'm not sure that I can explain the `static` part, but I would use `static const` instead of `static final` now. That's the usual way people define constants. I suppose you wouldn't need the `static` part. I think I've seen an explanation for that somewhere but I can't remember what it is now.

Answer (score -9):

1. get in pubspec.yaml
2. add

```
      dependency:  
          sqflite: any,   
          path_provider: any,   
          intl: ^0.15.7
```

3. then click package get and package upgrade