# 'Future' is from 'dart:async'. return null;

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dart-null-safety

```dart
Future insertToDatabase({
    required String title,
    required String data,
    required String time,
  }) async {
    return await database.transaction((txn) {
      txn
          .rawInsert(
              'INSERT INTO tasks(title, date, time, status) VALUES("$title","$data","$time","new")')
          .then((value) {
        print('$value inserted Done !!');
      }).catchError((err) {
        print('error insert to tables ${err.toString()}');
      });
      return null; 
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I hope it helps you ... try it <br>
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097327/3596519

Comment: `return null;` is not a future, you can simply remove this line .

Comment: 1. You haven't asked a question. 2. If you're asking why the `return null` line raises an analysis warning, the problem would be much more obvious if you switched to using `await` everywhere instead of using a mixture of `await` and `Future.then`.

Comment: what if there is no internet connection or bad internet connection? your user will wait forever, instead you should use `try` and `catch` for `future`, and set `timeOut`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem till now

```
  insertToDatabase({
    required String title,
    required String time,
    required String date,
  }) async {
    await database?.transaction((txn) {
      txn
          .rawInsert(
              'INSERT INTO tasks (title , date , time , status) VALUES ("$title $time" , "$date" , "new")')
          .then((value) {
        print('$value inserted successfully');
        emit(AppInsertDatabaseState());
        getDataFromDatabase(database);
      }).catchError((error) {
        print('Error When Inserting  new Records ${error.toString()}');
      });
      //throw Exception('Result unexpectedly null');
      print(null!);
```